# Excel changes the current working directory when .py file is called

Tags: python, excel, vba

My a.py file is located in "D:\Cockpit" folder and the python code gets the current directory of the file and saves it in a text file in the same folder. It uses os.getcwd() to get the file path.
When I run the python code it gives me as expected results ie D:\Cockpit folder in the text file.

However, I am trying to call this python file via batch file and from an excel macros file through VBA. When I do that, the location that I get is C:\Users\39215\Documents folder in the text file.

How can I change the VBA code or python code so that I get D:\Cockpit as the output?

Python Code:

```
import os

mainpath = str(os.getcwd())
errors = []
errors.append(mainpath)
fpath = r"D:\Cockpit\Path.txt"
f = open(fpath,"w+")
for i in errors:
    f.write("%s\r\n" % (i))
f.close()
```

VBA Code:

```
Sub RunAggregation()
    Dim oShell As Object, oCmd As String, cwd As String
    Dim oExec As Object, oOutput As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    cwd = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    oCmd = cwd & "\batch1.bat"
    MsgBox (oCmd)
    Set oExec = oShell.Exec(oCmd)
    Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut
    Set oOutput = Nothing: Set oExec = Nothing
    Set oShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have tried using ChDir "D:\Cockpit" in VBA, but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: What are the contents of the `batch1.bat` file?

Comment: What about changing the python file. put this line `os.chdir('D:\Cockpit')` before this line `mainpath = str(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Hello YasserKhalil, Thanks for your contribution, although, I want to avoid hardcoding 'D:\Cockpit' in the code. Is there are way around that? I want to keep it in such a wat that if i send this code to another person the path should be generated automatically.

Comment: But you already tried the same trick in VBA `ChDir "D:\Cockpit"`

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the python code

```
import os

os.chdir('D:\Cockpit')
mainpath = str(os.getcwd())
errors = []
errors.append(mainpath)
fpath = "Path.txt"

f = open(fpath, "w+")
for i in errors:
    f.write("%s\r\n" % (i))
f.close()
```